# npm 3 globally installed package not working

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have installed this [module](https://github.com/circabs/xl-json) globally however it fails with an error when run due to a dependency error however if I run my local copy by running the command

```
node ./bin/xl-json
```

the command works.  I believe when running the npm i -g xl-json command that dependencies aren't being installed properly.  Any ideas why one way works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because it is not [exactly] the same command you are running.

If you look at the error you see:

```
if (cptable === 'undefined') cptable = require('./dist/cpexcel');
                                     ^

ReferenceError: cptable is not defined
```

When you run the global command `xl-json`, the *.cmd* file (created by npm) takes precedence. iow. npm creates a file called xl-json.cmd which is a wrapper that invokes xl-json in the bin folder.

This file uses the *strict* option which the code should use but does not.

Try your command with `--use-strict` and you should see the same error message. i.e.:

```
node --use-strict ./bin/xl-json
```

Comment: np. Not sure if npm 3.0 forces the use of use-strict. Looking at other cmd files in the same directory I see it is not always there. But then again some  of these global modules I installed before npm 3

Comment: No I put use strict flag as my code is using const and let but it works without flag so have removed.